# Categrory URL Rewrite Not Working After Upgrading To Magento 2.3.1 from Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

After **upgrading** to **Magento 2.3.1** from **2.3.0**, **Category URL Rewrite** don't seem to be working.

After the update, now when I am creating a new product, the URL that's being generated is something like this: **http://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/3708/s/test-product-1/**. The correct format should have been **http://example.com/mobile-spare-parts/test-product-1/**.

My settings are as follows:

- Configuration >> General >> Web >> Search Engine Optimization >> Use Web Server Rewrites: **Yes**
- Configuration >> Catalog >> Search Engine Optimization >> Use Categories Path for Product URLs: **Yes**
- Configuration >> Catalog >> Search Engine Optimization >> Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories: **No**
- Configuration >> Catalog >> Search Engine Optimization >> Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products: **Yes**

**What seems to be working though is**, after creating a product, if I go and change the category to some other category, & save the product again, the URL re-write seems to be happening.

Again if I revert back to the original category, even now the URL re-write seems to be working with Clean URL being generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally after trying a good amount of 'this & that' for the past 3 days, I seem to have found my solution.

There can be numerous reasons for this issue to occurs; but in my case the issue was occurring due to one single reason, and that's mainly the '**Single Store Mode**' being turned '**On**'. For in-depth solution please visit the following link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5929#issuecomment-238170690.

> > Other handy solutions I would recommend:

**>> Solution using Extension:**

- https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites
- https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites
- https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls
- https://github.com/experius/Magento2-Module-Experius-ReindexCatalogUrlRewrites
- https://marketplace.magento.com/thlassche-regeneraterewrites.html [Don't Seem to support CE 2.3.x though]
- https://marketplace.magento.com/webpanda-catalog-url-rewrites.html
- https://firebearstudio.com/blog/url-rewrite-regeneration-extension-for-magento-2.html

> > If you are experiencing this issue after Migration from CE 1x to CE 2x, then try this: https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-tutorials/fixing-url-rewrite-after-migrating-magento-2/

Comment: The Experius Module linked above has been since deprecated. We have switched to using the elgentos module instead.